Issues with installation of dada2 using Biocmanager
I'm trying to install the 'dada2' package in R version 4.2.1 for a microbiome analysis pipeline and having some difficulties with installation.
I'm attempting to use Biocmanager with the following code:

if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("dada2", version = "3.16")

Once complete when I attempt to library data2 I get the following error.

library(dada2)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dada2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘interp’

I've attempted to download the 'interp' package separately using the following code, but it doesn't appear to be working.

install.packages("interp")

I'm relatively new to using R but do have some experience. Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks!

You need install.packages("/path/to/interp.tar.gz", repos=NULL) to install the download. However, obviously the BiocManager::install didn't complete successfully, you need to post relevant log where error messages start to occur during install, usually it fails and interrupts the process, so relevant stuff is at the end.
